# Opencv Java adjusting rectangle dimensions

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am working on licence plate detection in OpenCv, currently I can detect a licence plate [Sample of detected licence plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtuk8.png)

[image]

But the issue is the rectangle is too close to the licence plate characters, what I thought was I could just increase the dimensions by a given offset of which I did [Sample of increased offset detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCqWF.png)[image]

But unfortunately my understanding of the `Rect`is different from how it works, unlike the circle where you have a single point where it's drawn from, the rectangle uses 2 points, of which after increasing the dimensions, if shifts to the right(At least that is what it seems), I need help on centering the rectangle on its original location after increasing the offset, here is the code am using to increase it's dimensions

```
    rect.height = (int) (rect.height * 1.1);
    rect.width = (int) (rect.width * 1.5);
    Imgproc.rectangle(originalFrame, rect.br(), rect.tl(), new Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
```

I don't have enough rep yet so images do not display automatically.

Comment: The code was edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the right side's x coordinate by length, then you need to make all of the rectangle's coordinates go left length/2. The same applies to height.

```
rect.xCoord = rect.xCoord - ((rect.width * 1.1) - rect.width) / 2)
```

This goes before the first line of code you posted above. I'm not sure if this is how you access x coordinates in open cv (since I don't know it), so replace the x coord access with the actual one if this is wrong.

Comment: could you please demonstrate that? Am kind of slow on this.

Comment: well the code is not working, it pushes the rectangle further right